# Determine which key was pressed regardless form focus

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I wanna determine which key was pressed when im viewing a certain form. The problem is that if i want to check which key was pressed when im binding the "keypressed" event to the form, it won't show me which one was pressed if my focus is currently set  to lets say, a textbox, or a label, or a panel and so on.

Any way to do that even if the focus is currently set to a Panel, i can still determine which key was pressed? thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/6596489/2065121

Comment: this too .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674001/vb-net-capture-ctrlc/3680780#3680780

Comment: I see, so there is not an easy way to do it as i thought. Thanks!